# How can I share a custom dictionary between JetBrains Rider users and Visual Studio users?

Tags: visual-studio, spell-checking, rider

My team use both Visual Studio and Rider. I want to be able to share a custom dictionary so that both sets of users have the same spell-checking experience.

Spell checking is built into both Rider and Visual Studio, however, they both have different ways of managing custom dictionaries.

In Visual Studio, you can specify a custom dictionary with these lines `.editorconfig`:

```json
spelling_error_severity = warning
spelling_exclusion_path = .\custom-dictionary.DIC
spelling_checkable_types = strings,identifiers,comments
```

In Rider, you can specify custom dictionaries as either an XML file stored in the 'solution-shared' layer, or a word list file. The trouble I'm having with this is that:

- the solution-shared XML file is not available to Visual Studio as it only understands word list files
- the word list file must be configured on a user-by-user basis, e.g. each member of the team that uses Rider will have to go in and add the setting via `File/Settings/Editor/Spelling`, as it's stored as part of the user settings, e.g.:

> [image]

What would be idea is for Rider to pick up the configuration in `.editorconfig`. The next best alternative is for some Rider configuration stored **within the solution** (that is, checked into VCS), so that users get the same spell-checking experience **by default**.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER is probably the only place for such.